# Routes conflict in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am working with [Devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and I created a `show` page for users. My idea was to make a simple path like `www.website.com/:id` and I configured it as shown below:

```
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: {sing_in: "login", sing_out: 
     "signout", sing_up: "signup", edit: "edit"}, 
     :controllers => {:registrations => :registrations }
  resources :users, only: [:show]
  get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: :profile
```

My routes work fine but besides `show` page, I have pages under `static controller` for example `about` page. I want to be able to access it like `www.website.com/about`, here is how I define my `static routes`:

```
get '/about', to: 'static#about'
```

Now, if I am trying to redirect to `about page`, I am getting an error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=about
```

Here is my `users_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @services = @user.services
  end

  ...
end
```

I tried to search for the similar errors but haven't found anything like this. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Your route `get '/about', to: 'static#about'` should be defined before ` get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: :profile` route

Comment: Assuming you expect digits in users calls and letters in static pages calls, you can use constraints: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints

Comment: @lightalloy it was my first thought, but it won't work, since it's really call to static pages controller, as Author wrote.

Comment: @MarekLipka Thank you for your answer. What if letter on I want to add numeric values to other pages (ex.:`www.website/123`)? Is there any other similar solution?

Comment: Routes are matched from top to bottom. Did @lightalloy’s suggestion not work for you? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @inveterateliterate it does, but I am trying to figure out the problem that Marek Lipka highlighted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things here:

- Routes are ignorant of param types
- Routes are matched top to bottom

In this case, I suspect that your single level routes are being defined your `get '/:id'` route. Therefore, that route is catching all requests which are `/anything` because the router thinks `anything` is a parameter.

Simply move your route definition below any other `/about` etc routes so that they are matched first.

Like this:

```
get '/about', to: 'static#about'
get '/:id' => 'users#show', as: :profile
```

Comment: added a code example and it's also good to be aware @AnthonyBrooks that you need to add validation to prevent user's from having the same id/slug/name as any defined route; this will prevent user frustration (just in case someone does try to put in 'about' as their username ;-) )

Comment: @RudolfOlah wow, I haven't thought about it... good point! Thank you very much!